# Bday finder using input java

Tags: java

why isnt this working

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
  // write your code here
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter year: ");
    int year = scan.nextInt();
    int age = 0;
    System.out.println("is your bday complete this year: ans 'Y/N'");
    String bday= scan.nextLine();
    scan.close();
    if (bday=="Y"||bday=="y"){
        age = 2021-year;
    }else if(bday=="N"||bday=="n"){
        age = 2020-year;
    }else{
        System.out.println("wrong input");
    }
    System.out.println(age);
  }
}
```

Comment: please include the expected output as part of your answer

Comment: What isn't working? Please tell us, we're not here to do your debugging for you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `equals()` method to compare strings. In this case it is better to use `equalsIgnoreCase()`. Update the `if` and `else if` as below:

```java
if (bday.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
    age = 2021-year;
}else if(bday.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
    age = 2020-year;
}
```